# Python inverse/negative/non-present values in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like:

```
col1 | col2
------------
A    |   1
A    |   2
B    |   3
C    |   4
C    |   5
C    |   6
```

I want to map all the values of column B to A which is currently not present. ie

I want to convert it to:

```
col1 | col2
------------
A    |   3
A    |   4
A    |   5
A    |   6
B    |   1
B    |   2
B    |   4
B    |   5
B    |   6
C    |   1
C    |   2
C    |   3
```

How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape to wide, mask existing cell as `nan` and reshape back, which drops the existing pair of index:

```
(pd.crosstab(df.col1, df.col2)
   .where(lambda x: x == 0)
   .stack().reset_index()
   .drop(0, 1))

#   col1  col2
#0     A     3
#1     A     4
#2     A     5
#3     A     6
#4     B     1
#5     B     2
#6     B     4
#7     B     5
#8     B     6
#9     C     1
#10    C     2
#11    C     3
```

Another option based on index manipulation that could be more efficient:

```
idx_full = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.col1.unique(), df.col2.unique()])
idx_now = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.values.tolist())
pd.DataFrame(idx_full.difference(idx_now).tolist(), columns=df.columns)
```

written as a function:

```
def anti_complete(df):
    idx_full = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df[col] for col in df.columns])
    idx_now = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.values.tolist())
    return pd.DataFrame(idx_full.difference(idx_now).tolist(), columns=df.columns)
​
print(anti_complete(df))
#   col1  col2
#0     A     3
#1     A     4
#2     A     5
#3     A     6
#4     B     1
#5     B     2
#6     B     4
#7     B     5
#8     B     6
#9     C     1
#10    C     2
#11    C     3
```

Comment: Let me try and revert!

Comment: It works, as this was the first answer hence marking this as right.

Comment: Another option would be `pd.crosstab(df.col1, df.col2).replace({1: np.nan}).stack()...`

Answer (score 2):

```
df1=df.reset_index().set_index(['col1','col2']).unstack()
v=df1.stack(dropna=False)
v[v['index'].isnull()].reset_index().dropna(1)

Out[554]: 
   col1  col2
0     A   3.0
1     A   4.0
2     A   5.0
3     A   6.0
4     B   1.0
5     B   2.0
6     B   4.0
7     B   5.0
8     B   6.0
9     C   1.0
10    C   2.0
11    C   3.0
```